# Datatables adding search by column changes the size of table

Tags: laravel, search, filter, datatable, datatables

I addedd `<tfoot>` on my table and the table is like 2x bigger more than before:

```
<div class="container">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="users-table" style="white-space: nowrap; margin: auto;">
            <thead class="table-primary">
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Verified Status</th>
                    <th>User Type</th>
                    <th>Birthdate</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Fiscal ID</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot class="table-info">
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Verified Status</th>
                    <th>User Type</th>
                    <th>Birthdate</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Fiscal ID</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

this is the script for datables:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: false,
        serverSide: true,
        columnDefs: [
        {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"}
        ],
        ajax: '{{ route('admin.users-data') }}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'user', name: 'user' },
            { data: 'email_verified_at', name: 'users.email_verified_at', 
                render: function( data, type, full, meta ) {
                    if (data == null) {
                      return "<img class=\"\" src=\"{{ asset('images/icons/no.png')}}\" style=\"width:20%\"/>";
                    } else {
                      return "<img class=\"\" src=\"{{ asset('images/icons/yes.png')}}\" style=\"width:20%\"/>";
                    }
                    
                  
                }
            },
            { data: 'role', name: 'roles.role' },
            { data: 'birthdate', name: 'birthdate' },
            { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
            { data: 'fiscal_id', name: 'fiscal_id' },
            { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable:false }
        ],
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every(function () {
                var column = this;
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                .on('change', function () {
                    column.search($(this).val(), false, false, true).draw();
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

When I added footer on table for searching by column the size of the table change, its twice bigger and it does not accept any style on it.

Can someone explain why this is happening, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 4 questions I've made in stavkoverflow, in all 4 of them I answered to myself...

Anyway, who is struggling with this just add this to your css:

```
tfoot input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Happy coding!